# Писал код расыльщика на python, используя pyrogram, но код сообщение пересылалось не то

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, pyrogram

При выполнении этого кода, все работает правильно, сообщение действительно отправляется, но есть один нюанс
сообщение отправляется совершенно не то, которое нужно.
Смысл кода в том, что клиент читает последнее сообщение из сохраненных сообщений и отправляет это сообщение в чаты, которые указываются в начале скрипта, но как раз таки здесь есть тот самый нюанс, отправляет он не нужное сообщение а вот это вот ".async_to_sync_gen at 0x0000021AEDCE59E0>"
Кто сможет помочь, решить эту проблему?

```
from pyrogram import Client, errors
from sys import stderr
from loguru import logger
import time


api_id = 29748653  # Сюда вставляете свой api_id полученный с сайта https://my.telegram.org/
api_hash = "2f3f2518c6b06274fbd2224a35001cc2"  # Сюда вставляете свой api_hash полученный с сайта https://my.telegram.org/

SESSION_NAME = input('Please, enter session name: ')
logger.remove()
logger.add(stderr,
           format='<white>{time:HH:mm:ss}</white> | '
                  '<level>{level: <8}</level> | '
                  '<cyan>{line}</cyan> - '
                  '<white>{message}</white>')


proxy = {
     "scheme": "socks5",  # "socks4", "socks5" and "http" are supported
     "hostname": "194.28.210.105",
     "port": 9470,
     "username": "LzfXMj",
     "password": "tt2ZN4"
}


app = Client(SESSION_NAME, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, proxy=proxy)

interval = 10 # интервал между сообщениями в секундах

#try:
    #message_text = app.get_chat_history("me") # получаем текст из последнего в истории сообщений
#except IndexError:
    #print("No text messages found in chat history. Using default message.")
    #message_text = "Hello, everyone!"  # текст сообщения по умолчанию


chat_type = input("Choose chat source (1 - text file, 2 - joined chats): ")
if chat_type == "1":
    chat_links_file = input("Enter path to chat links file: ")
    with open(chat_links_file, "r") as f:
        chat_links = f.readlines() # читаем ссылки на чаты из файла
elif chat_type == "2":
    dialogs = app.get_dialogs()
    chat_links = [f"{dialog.chat.username}" for dialog in dialogs if dialog.chat.type == "group" or dialog.chat.type == "supergroup"]
else:
    print("Invalid input. Using default chat list.")
    dialogs = app.get_dialogs()
    chat_links = [f"{dialog.chat.username}" for dialog in dialogs if dialog.chat.type == "group" or dialog.chat.type == "supergroup"]


with app:
    while True: # бесконечный цикл для повторения рассылки
        for chat_link in chat_links:
            try:
                chat = app.get_chat(chat_link)  # получаем информацию о чате по ссылке
                app.send_message(chat_id=chat.id, text=app.get_chat_history("me", limit=1))  # отправляем сообщение в текущий чат
            except errors.FloodWait as e:
                print(f"Sleeping for {e.x} seconds...")
                time.sleep(e.x)
            except errors.ChatWriteForbidden:
                print(f"Cannot send message to {chat_link}. Skipping...")
        time.sleep(interval) # задержка перед следующей рассылкой

app.run()
```

Пробовал делать это, через пересылку сообщений из сохраненных сообщений, но тут уже в другом проблема... Мне пересылалось, какое-то абсолютно рандомное сообщение от Telegram, но никак не из избранных.
Может, кто знает, как можно грамотно наладить пересылку, чтобы пересылалось последнее сообщение из сохраненных сообщений

```
#app.get_chat_history("me", limit=1)  # получаем текст из последнего в истории сообщений
                #app.forward_messages(chat_id=chat.id, from_chat_id="me", message_ids=1) # отправляем сообщение в текущий чат
```